# Estimate the difference between her February and her December spending

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image]

my try for part 1:

water for February =20

water for December =20

water difference spending = 20 -20 =0

gas for February =45

gas for December =35

gas difference spending = 45 -35 =10

electricity for February =29

electricity for December =30

electricity difference spending = 30 -29 =1

is that correct ??

and about part 2 , I don't understand it and need help

Answer (score 0):

Your calculations for water and gas look correct. However, you say the electricity expense for February was $29$ and for December was $30$. To my eyes, February's gas mark seems to be on the same horizontal line as December's and looks to be $30$. So I would put the electricity difference as $30-30=0$.

However, you overlook that the question was for the spending difference "for all three utilities combined." You should combine the three differences by adding. Therefore the answer to the first question is $0+10+0=10$.

---

Part 2 asks about the basic [field properties](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics)#Definition_and_illustration). The ones used in your problem are:

a) replacing $8(n+5)$ with $8\cdot n+8\cdot 5$. This is the *distributive property of multiplication over addition*.

b) replacing $8n+40$ with $40+8n$. This is the *commutative property of addition*.

c) replacing $15+(40+8n)$ with $(15+40)+8n$. This is the *associative property of addition*.

d) replacing $55+17n$ with $17n+55$. This is the *commutative property of addition* again.